# I need validation method in java

Tags: java, arrays, validation, methods

I need to make atm machine for school project.
I finished all and all is working fine, and i make the validation for the pin because it is string. So my problem is how to make validation for all other methods to check if anything else but numbers is entered to say the user that is wrong and to return him on the start of that method. All variables are stored into array as integers.

So here is my code please help i tried so many things and i cant make it work..

```
public class Banka {

    static Scanner skener = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String pin[] = {"1234","2345","3456","4567","5678"};
    static String username[] = {"Mate","Nathan","John","Michelle","Angelina"};
    static int balance[] = {200,100,250,150,300};
    static boolean overdraft[] = {true,true,false,true,false};
    static int index;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        login();
    }
    public static void login() {
        Date datum = new Date();
        System.out.println("" +datum);
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Illuminati Bank \n Please log in with your PIN");
        String login = skener.next();
        checkpin(login);
        for (int i = 0; i< pin.length; i++) {
            if (login.matches(pin[i])) {
                index = i;
                System.out.println("\nWelcome " + username[index]);
                Menu();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Wrong PIN entered, please login again \n");
        login();  
    }
    public static void Menu() {
        System.out.println("Please select an option");
        System.out.println("\n 1.View Bank Statement \n 2.Deposit \n 3.Withdraw \n 4.Change Pin \n 5.Exit \n");
        int choice = skener.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1: statement();
              break;
            case 2: deposit();
              break;
            case 3: withdraw();
              break;
            case 4: change();
              break;
            case 5: exit();
              break;
            default: System.out.println("Incorrect Choice ");
        Menu();
        } 
    }
    public static void statement() {
        switch(index) {
            case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
                System.out.println("" +username[index]+ ", your balance is: " +balance[index]+ "€");
                if (overdraft[index] == true) {
                    System.out.println("You are entitled to overdraft");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("You are NOT entitled to overdraft");
                }
                Menu();
        }
    }
    public static void deposit() {
        System.out.println("" +username[index]+ ", how much you wish to deposit?");
        int deposit = skener.nextInt();
        balance[index] = balance[index] + deposit;
        System.out.println("Thank you, you deposited " +deposit+ "€, now you have " +balance[index]+ "€ total");
        depositm();
    }
    public static void depositm(){
        System.out.println("\n 1.Deposit more \n 2.Exit to menu");
        int more = skener.nextInt();
        switch (more) {
            case 1: deposit();
            break;
            case 2: Menu();
            default: System.out.println("Wrong choice, please choose again");
            depositm();
        }
    }
    public static void withdraw() {
        System.out.println("" +username[index]+ ", how much you wish to withdraw?");
        int withdraw = skener.nextInt();
        if (overdraft[index] == true) {
            balance[index] = balance[index] - withdraw;
            System.out.println("Thank you, you withdrawed the money, now you have " +balance[index]+ "€");
            Menu();
        }
        if(overdraft[index] == false && balance[index] >= withdraw) 
        {balance[index] = balance[index] - withdraw;
        System.out.println("Thank you, you withdrawed the money, now you have " +balance[index]+ "€");
        Menu();
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("You have insufficient funds \nPlease try again");
        withdraw();
        } 
    }
    public static void change() {
        System.out.println("" +username[index]+ ", do you want to change your pin?");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to change or 2 to exit to menu");
        int change = skener.nextInt();
        switch (change) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Please enter new PIN");
            pin[index] = skener.next();
            System.out.println("You successfully changed your PIN");
            Menu();
            case 2: System.out.println("Your PIN remains unchanged");
            Menu();
            default: System.out.println("Wrong choice, please choose again");
            change();
        }
    }
    public static void exit(){
        System.out.println("Goodbye " +username[index]+ ", Illuminati Bank wish you all the best \n");
        login();
    }
    public static int checkpin(String x){
        while(!x.matches("\\d{4}")){
            System.err.println("\n Error.\n Please enter 4 digit pin.");
            login();
       }
        return 0;    
    }
}
```

so if any one can help me how to validate all other methods with user inputs where is INTs that would be great.

Comment: So you are getting a string input and want to validate the string contains only digits?

Comment: Check if `Integer.parseInt(yourString)` throws a `NumberFormatException`. If the input string is not a valid integer said exception is thrown and you could catch it and take action accordingly

Comment: int deposit = skener.nextInt();
how to validate that and all others like that to check if user input is only digits?

Comment: ..using a new method. like i have for login method with checkpin.

Comment: @MateVlahović Use `String input = skener.nextLine();` with my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54789999/2408342).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String input = "xxxx";
int pin;
try{
    pin = Integer.parseInt(input);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // input contains letters or symbols.
}
```

---

Or here's another one using the [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class.

```
String input = "xxxx";
boolean allDigits = true;
for(char ch: input.toCharArray()){
    if(!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        allDigits = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(allDigits){
    // input contains only digits.
}
```

---

**Edit:** Answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789918/i-need-validation-method-in-java/54789999#comment96360087_54789999) comment.

You can modify your method like this,

```
public static void checkpin(String x) {
    if (x.length() == 4) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(x);
            login();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("\n Error.\n Invalid pin.");
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("\n Error.\n Please enter 4 digit pin.");
    }
}
```

this way the method `login()` is called only if the pin has 4 digits and all the digits are numbers.

Comment: i cant use aray list and i need to make method like this one which checks for pin just this another one needs to check all otgher user inputs into scanner

public static int checkpin(String x){
        while(!x.matches("\\d{4}")){
            System.err.println("\n Error.\n Please enter 4 digit pin.");
            login();
       }
        return 0;    
    }

Comment: @MateVlahović check the answer now.

Comment: i dont need to modify login method i need to make another one like that to check all other inputs because all other methods use INTEGERS not string and i cant make method with string to check for ints because of error

Comment: and if i change this int deposit = skener.nextInt(); 
to that String deposit = skener.nextLine(); 
then other result is not working because of this error
https://imgur.com/jUCxZee